# Get delete value of a table from the oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I just recently deleted data from the `Oracle` database from one of the table.

Can anyone let me know how to get table that data back ??

My table name is `XXACL_PN_SUPINV_MENU_HDR`

Comment: Putting this comment here too so you see it.  Make a backup of a table BEFORE doing risky testing: `create table XXACL_PN_SUPINV_MENU_HDR_BKUP as select * from XXACL_PN_SUPINV_MENU_HDR;` and if you want only the structure without data: `create table XXACL_PN_SUPINV_MENU_HDR_NEW as select * from XXACL_PN_SUPINV_MENU_HDR WHERE 1=2;` "An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure" - Benjamin Franklin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get the data back if you have executed your query inside a transaction. If the query was inside a transaction then you can use [ROLLBACK statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/rollback_statement.htm) to get the data back. But if your query was not inside a transaction, then there is no way to get the data back.

Comment: i didn't used `ROLLBACK` statement :(

Comment: can i get the data from the backup ??

Comment: i think no, i simply added query like this `delete from XXACL_PN_SUPINV_MENU_HDR`

Comment: @learner:- If you have the backup then yes you can get it from there.

Comment: how to check backup in oracle and restore the data for that table ?

Comment: He can maybe use timestamp?

Comment: @sagi; can you explain in detail, how to check that ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm it show you how the table looked in a specifiec date you provide

Comment: hey, I just did `ROLLBACK` from the toad, and I got my data back :)

Comment: what was that ?? something strange ?? can anyone explain me how just did it came back ?

Comment: @learner:- That is probably because your data was not committed and hence when you tried to rollback it, you got your data back. :)

Comment: strange, but lucky me this time. I will take care very much of this in future

Comment: Thats what @RahulTripathi was trying to say, where you are making DML commands(insert/update/delete) in a transaction(an sql window that is open), for it to apply to the database and not only in the opened window you need to use COMMIT which will apply your commands(When u close the window usually it either asks u to commit or commit by itself) If you didn't commit, you can always ROLLBACK which will as it sound, rollback what ever you did and won't apply any of it on the DB

Comment: Experience is what you get right after you need it. :-)

Comment: Oh and you can always make a backup of a table BEFORE doing risky testing too:  `create table XXACL_PN_SUPINV_MENU_HDR_BKUP as select * from XXACL_PN_SUPINV_MENU_HDR`; and if you want only the structure without data: `create table XXACL_PN_SUPINV_MENU_HDR_NEW as select * from XXACL_PN_SUPINV_MENU_HDR WHERE 1=2`;  "An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure"

Answer (score 1):

I realize you already recovered your data, but if you had committed the changes, a quick way to recover it is by using a flashback query back to a timestamp before your delete. You can select the row by the primary key if you know and just insert it back with a INSERT .. SELECT.

```
SELECT *
  FROM XXACL_PN_SUPINV_MENU_HDR AS OF TIMESTAMP(to_timestamp('27-JAN-2016 10:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) t;
```